# Click counter on a div using php

Tags: php, javascript

I know nothing about javascript, but I'm using javascript in a couple places on my site to make it look a little nicer. One of these places is where when a user clicks a div, it can open a nice looking popup with more information. However, I also want to save the number of clicks a div has.

I know how I could do this with php, and I've managed to find some javascript code that could increment a variable, but I don't think those two can be combined unless the js saves the var as a cookie, which I think could have some security flaws if I'm then reading the js variable back into the database.

The javascript code I have is

```
/*Click counter*/
var clicks = 0;
function count() 
{
    document.getElementById( "cc" ).value = ++clicks;
}
```

and I'm not sure of where to start with the php since I don't know the javascript. But querying the database to increment the column that stores the number of clicks will be simple. I just don't know how to tell php that a click has been made using javascript. I don't think it can be done in php, unless the link goes to a php file which handles all of this first and then redirects, which won't work in this case since the popup wouldn't be loaded in the new page.

Any ideas or pseudo-code to help?

Comment: You are right, you have to issue an AJAX request per click, which is just an HTTP request in background. On your server side you query database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AJAX to update the server database if you want to keep the counter up to date on the server side.

Based on [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_database.htm), here's a quick example:

mydiv.phtml:

```
<?php $_GET['id']=isset($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:1; include 'count.php'; ?>
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
var clickerid = <?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>; //counter id allows easy implementation of other counters if desired
var clicks = <?php echo $clicks ?>;
var clickLock = false;
var maxClickRate = 1000; //maximum click rate in ms, so the server won't choke
//Browser Support Code
function count(){
 if (clickLock) { 
     alert('you\'re clicking too fast!'); 
     return;
 }
 clickLock=true;
 setTimeout('clickLock=false;',maxClickRate);
 var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

 try{
   // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
   ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }catch (e){
   // Internet Explorer Browsers
   try{
      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   }catch (e) {
      try{
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e){
         // Something went wrong
         alert("Your browser broke!");
         return false;
      }
   }
 }
 // Create a function that will receive data 
 // sent from the server and will update
 // div section in the same page.
 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      document.getElementById('cc').innerHTML = ++clicks;
   }
 }
 // Now pass clicks value to the
 // server script.
 var queryString = "?id=" + clickerid + "&update=true";
 ajaxRequest.open("GET", "count.php" + 
                              queryString, true);
 ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
//-->
</script>
<div onclick='count()'>
<form name='myForm'>
<input type='button' value='clickOnDiv'/>
</form>
</div>
Clicks so far: <span id='cc'><?php echo $clicks; ?></span>
</body>
</html>
```

count.php:

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'password');
    if (!isset($_GET['update'])){
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT count
        FROM clicks
        WHERE id = :clickerid');
        $stmt->bindValue(':clickerid', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $clicks = $result['count'];
    } else {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE clicks
        SET count = count + 1
        WHERE id = :clickerid');
        $stmt->bindValue(':clickerid', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "PDO Exception.";
    die();
}
?>
```

set_database.php:

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost', 'user', 'password');
    $dbh->query('CREATE DATABASE test;');
    $dbh->query('CREATE TABLE test.clicks (id INT KEY, count INT);');
    $dbh->query('INSERT INTO test.clicks VALUES (1,0);');
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "PDO Exception.";
    die();
}
?>
```